# Adding button.py to graphics.py

Tags: python

I decided to make a python project with the graphics.py library that I learned back in high school. I have successfully installed it using the command seen in the comments down below. I have no trouble using it as it is slowly coming back to me as I code. But then I decided that I needed to make a button object. I quickly realized that buttons weren't included in the graphics.py library, but I found this Button python class online from http://mcsp.wartburg.edu/zelle/python/ppics1/code/chapter12/button.py. I want to add this to the graphics.py library on my MacBook so I can easily access it when I make Python graphics projects, but I'm having trouble finding the path to where it is installed. Is there any way I could do this?

Comment: refer to this site under MackBook to see the command I used: http://www.pas.rochester.edu/~rsarkis/csc161/python/pip-graphics.html

Comment: Try: `import graphics; print(graphics.__file__)`

Comment: Thanks! Worked Perfectly!